# Как сделать нумерованный список с точкой?

Tags: html, css, css3

Как сделать список формата.

- 1.Главный пункт (жирный текст.)
- 1.1 Подпункт
- 1.2 Подпункт
- 1.3 Подпункт

---

- 2.Главный пункт (жирный текст.)
- 2.1 Подпункт
- 2.2 Подпункт
- 2.3 Подпункт

---

Я когда через простые абзацы сделал, то столкнулся с проблемой если текста много, то он переносится под пункт меню, а 1.1 1.2 - должен быть типо как маркер и всегда быть справа, под ним не должно быть текста при переносе.

Comment: @Sevastopol' https://jsfiddle.net/5d1xc4y9/1/ Вот я немного сделал, + li разобрался, добавив просто флекс, но с главным пунктом меню жирным текстом, чето неполучается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всю нумерацию можно собрать из [CSS-counter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter()) и добавить к ним символ `•`

```css
body {
  counter-reset: bubu;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  counter-reset: sub-bubu;
}

.title::before {
  counter-increment: bubu;
  content: "• " counter(bubu) ". ";
}

.ul li:not(.title)::before {  
  counter-increment: sub-bubu;  
  content: "• " counter(bubu) "." counter(sub-bubu);
}

.ul li {
  display: flex;
}

.ul li::before {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul">
  <li class="title">Главный пункт</li>
  <li>Подпункт</li>
  <li>Подпункт</li>
  <li>Подпункт</li>
</ul>

<ul class="ul">
  <li class="title">Главный пункт</li>
  <li>Подпункт</li>
  <li>Подпункт</li>
  <li>Подпункт test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: спасибо, почитаю подробнее про каунтеры, у меня по сути получилось самому сделать, но как то кривовато все было.